# Determing whats land and whats water in php

Tags: php, laravel

So consider the following image:

[image]

this is a 350x350 px png image.

I wrote the following **laravel 5.7** code to determining what is and isn't water:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use App\Modules\Locations\Services\CreateMapService;
use ChristianEssl\LandmapGeneration\Struct\Color;
use App\Modules\Locations\Models\Location;

class SurfaceLocations extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $water = new Color(66, 129, 178);
        $land  = new Color(23, 132, 72);

        $createImage = new CreateMapService($land, $water, 350, 350, 'random_map');
        $createImage->generateMap('surface');

        $contents      = Storage::disk('maps')->get('surface.png');
        $imageResource = imagecreatefromstring($contents);

        $waterR = 112;
        $waterG = 219;
        $waterB = 255;

        for ($x = 0; $x <= 349; $x++) {
            for($y = 0; $y <= 349; $y++) {

                $rgb = imagecolorat($imageResource, $x, $y);

                $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

                if ($r === $waterR && $g === $waterG && $b === $waterB) {
                    Location::create([
                        'x' => $x,
                        'y' => $y,
                        'is_water' => true
                    ]);
                } else {
                    Location::create([
                        'x' => $x,
                        'y' => $y,
                        'is_water' => false
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, it takes a bit of time, but it works. It sets `is_water` to true when we encounter the blue aspect of the picture.

What I want to do now is check if, not only is the pixel we are on water, but if the one next to it is not, randomly check (`rand(0, 100) >= 50`) if we should set a `is_port` to true.

The idea here is the set a port along the "shore", but only do it sometimes. (so that every pixel of shore line is not a port, but there may be one or more ports along said shore.

The logic I have right now can be modified to check that, but the question is how?

The only thing I can think of is incrementing the x and y as well as decrementing them and checking those values if they are not water when we are on water, and if they are not, check if we passed the "check" and if so set `is_port` to true.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's wrong with what you proposed?

Comment: When you say "the one next to it", what do you mean precisely? A square pixel has either 4 or 8 neighbours, depending if you want to count diagonals.

Comment: @IMSoP as you can see `imagecolorat` takes and x, y so I think, in theory, it would be right, left, up, down. But now that you mention that, I might as well include diagonal.

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne The reason I asked was because I was wondering if there's a better approach

Comment: Your code could be optimized. Don't compare R,G and B, compare RGB together

Comment: What dimensions will your final maps be? A much more efficient data structure for processing the coastline would be one where you find all contiguous green blocks (i.e. islands) and find their perimeters (coastlines); store those perimeters in doubly-linked 'circular' lists. The items in those lists would point to your actual pixels

Comment: There's quite a lot of different ways you *could* do this, but "better" is fairly subjective. Do you mean "faster"? Or "easier to read in the code"? Or some other metric?

Comment: Don't do inserts one by one, use batch insert instead... 349*349 inserts, holy crap :D

Comment: @Kyslik Care to demonstrate how you would do a batch insert? Specifically with something like this

Comment: Store the stuff in `$array[] = [‘x’ => ,’y’,...]` and then just `Location::insert($array)` all in one go or maybe just make 349 inserts consisting of 349 *locations* at one time (put the insert in outer for loop).

Comment: Database is your only bottleneck; and also the `imagecolorat` function.

Comment: @Kyslik also the image creating stuff is also the bottle neck.

Comment: No, that is not the bottleneck in the scope of the *algorithm* its outside of the for loops, thus not impacting the speed... if you pre-compute (pre-generate) images and just read them afterwards the *image creating* is non-issue. The biggest bottleneck are inserts, second biggest is the `imagecolorat` and the last is the algorithm itself.

Comment: Here is a gist, https://gist.github.com/Kyslik/5b9a66b9b0852c91f1310c279a9f2543. Besides that, do your port thing the naive way and make it work - use smaller images for testing / developing, later on try to optimize. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a thought, but in a school project I used a connectivity algorithm to check pixels adjacency, they are available through a quick google search on google and implemented on many languages so maybe you could look for one that fits and adapt it to your needs as far as "is_water" on pixel and neighbor pixels checking.

That combined with a flag to determine whether yoy put a port or not should solve the problem.

Also just to point out that  (rand(0, 100) >= 50) would be same as (rand(0, 2) >= 1) (I think) at a 50% chance of being a port...maybe you can tweak that to fit your port population.

Hope I could help :D

Comment: Please can you add to your answer a sample code of algorithm to check for pixels adjacency?